# When does $U\subset V$ induce maps on homology of finite rank?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, homology-cohomology

> **Question 1.** Let $X$ be a topological manifold, $U\subset V\subset X$ open subsets. The inclusion $\iota:U\to V$ induces corresponding maps on homology $\iota_*:H_\bullet(U)\to H_\bullet(V)$. We take the coefficients to lie in some fixed field. Under what conditions can we conclude that $\iota_*$ has finite rank (as a linear map)? In particular, I am interested in whether the following is sufficient: $\overline{U}\subset V$ and $\overline{U}$ is compact.

I encountered this problem when reading Gromov's paper *Curvature, diameter and Betti numbers*. The setting is on a complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ where we may consider balls $B(p,r):=\{x\in M:d(p,x)<r\}$. The *content* of such a ball is defined by $$\operatorname{cont}B(p,r):=\operatorname{rank}(B(p,r/5)\subset B(p,r)),$$ where the rank refers to the rank of the induced map on homology. I need to know that this number is always finite.

I encountered the second question when reading the proof of the results in the aforementioned paper of Gromov in the book *Riemannian Geometry* by Peter Petersen. The author remarks without proof the following:

> **Question 2.** Notation as above. For $r$ large enough, $$\operatorname{cont}B(p,r)=\sum b_i(M)$$ where $b_i:=\dim H_i(M)$ is the Betti number of $M$.

Now this is obvious if $M$ is compact. But why is it true for noncompact complete manifolds?

I'm a bit rusty on algebraic topology, but I really don't see why these should hold. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You get Gromov's Betti number theorem for $(M,g)$ connected, non-compact and $K_g \ge 0$ using the soul theorem of Cheeger and Gromoll.

Comment: @Mathy That's a good idea! Thanks! It seems that it also follows from the critical point theory of Grove–Shiohama.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, it is sufficient for $U$ to be precompact in $V$ when $X$ is smooth.  In that case, you can triangulate $V$.  Since $\overline{U}$ is compact, it is covered by finitely many cells of the triangulation, and so there is a finite simplicial complex $K$ such that $\overline{U}\subseteq K\subseteq V$.  Then the map $H_*(U)\to H_*(V)$ factors through the finite-dimensional space $H_*(K)$, so it has finite rank.

(I suspect it is also true for topological manifolds but don't see a proof at the moment.  It would suffice, for instance, to show there is a compact manifold with boundary $K$ such that $\overline{U}\subseteq K\subseteq V$, since compact manifolds with boundary also have finitely generated homology.)

For the second question, the statement is just wrong without some additional assumption about $M$.  Indeed, every manifold admits a complete metric, so if you take a manifold $M$ with infinitely generated homology, the statement cannot be true.

It can even be false for manifolds with finitely generated homology.  For instance, take a smooth map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ which is $0$ except that it has spikes near the points $(n,0)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which get higher and higher very fast as $n\to\infty$.  Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be the graph of $f$ with the induced metric.  Then $M\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible, but the content of arbitrarily large balls will be nontrivial, since they (and the subball with $1/5$ the radius) will contain the bottom of the spikes in the graph but not the top so there will be noncontractible loops in them.